# I can't Install ITK on my system

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake, itk

I am having a hard time installing itk on my computer :( 
I am just following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6W-S9ZpArYM

I have created a folder, named ITK, with three subfolders : Source, Cmake, and Build.

- Source has all the folders and files of itk-insightToolkit.
- Cmake has all the folders and files of CMAKE.

And then, I have used Cmake\bin\cmake-gui.exe, to generate the containers of Build folder.

In the last step, when I am building ALL_BUILD project, I am getting the below errors:

[image]

I don't know how to fix it. I would be thankful if anyone can help me through this.
Thanks.

UPDATE:
This problem has been solved by re-installing Visual Studio and updating it to Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Images are not searchable, please include the _text_ of the error messages in your post.

Comment: i am not sure about that file path... are you by chance using something in a zip folder without extracting it before ?